# jQuery sliding banner mouseover&clearInterval doesn't work

Tags: jquery, slide, banner, clearinterval

I have successfully created a sliding banner using jQuery,however when I tried to use `.mouseover(function(){ clearInterval() }` which means while move the mouse in the picture the sliding banner will stop sliding, this doesn't work.

```
$("#wrapper-banner > div:gt(0)").hide();

var timer=setInterval(function() {
    $('#wrapper-banner > div:first')
        .fadeOut(3000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(3000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#wrapper-banner');
}, 4000);


("#wrapper-banner").mouseover(function(){
  clearInterval(timer);
});
```

Comment: ("#wrapper-banner") is missing $, but you have this ok in your code right?

Comment: Thank you man! This is another low-level error I've made from yesterday!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you man! This is another low-level error I've made from yesterday!